# Multiple Sub Event in one place

Tags: vb.net, events

Right now in my main Form, I have:

```
Public Sub TextBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Click
    Me.TextBox1.SelectAll()
End Sub

Public Sub TextBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.Click
    Me.TextBox2.SelectAll()
End Sub

Public Sub TextBox3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.Click
    Me.TextBox3.SelectAll()
End Sub
```

Which is not practical and I would like to know if there is a way to put all this Event in one place and after call it in the main Form, for example:

```
Module selectall
    Public Sub Form1.TextBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Form1.TextBox1.Click
        Form1.TextBox1.SelectAll()
    End Sub

Public Sub Form1.TextBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Form1.TextBox2.Click
        Form1.TextBox2.SelectAll()
    End Sub

Public Sub Form1.TextBox3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Form1.TextBox3.Click
        Form1.TextBox3.SelectAll()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: If you have just one method call for all, use the same event handler for all your textboxes, casting `sender` to TextBox (or TextBoxBase).

Comment: You're handling the wrong event. As it is, if the control already has focus and the user clicks somewhere in the text to position the caret, you're going to select all the text. Don't see how that makes sense. If what you actually want is for the full text to be selected each time the control gets focus then handle the event that is raised each time the control gets focus, regardless of how that happens, and not at other times. That event is `Enter`.

Comment: I see what you mean but for what I wanted to do, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
Public Sub TextBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Click, TextBox2.Click, TextBox3.Click
     CType(sender, TextBox).SelectAll()
End Sub
```